# How to debug and trace the call of function in Java?

Tags: java, debugging, monitoring, profiler

I have a function in DAO layer which is being called multiple times.

I need to investigate from where is this function is being called, like REST call / Service / other end point.

I know that I can make it using uploading new version to production with and enhance logs with more information, to me it seems like not the best option.

Is there a way to find how many times this function is being called and what is the root cause of it using a profiler to find my answer ?

Comment: You can find out who called a method by creating an `Exception` object and reading out the stack trace.

Comment: I thought about it also, it can cause my log file fulfilled very fast

Comment: You just want the second stack trace element as it tells you the calling method.

Comment: And maybe you just want to count the different calls...

Comment: @dan1st I want to have a stacktrace of a specific function which currently is calling most times and investigate why it's happening

Comment: You may want to use a `HashMap<Exception,Integer>` if the equals and hashCode of the Exception work...